# How to remove ':hover' when using a touchscreen?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, tablet

When this code runs on a tablet/mobile, the user has to tap twice to reach the linked URL. Instead, is there a way to remove the hover effect when viewing on a touchscreen device without using '@media screen and (max-width: XXXpx)'? - I would really like the hover effect to remain on a desktop site, no matter what width a desktop browser is resized to.

Many thanks in advance!

```css
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
}
#one {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#one:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
#one:hover > #hello {
  display: none;
}
#one:hover > #world {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
#hello {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
#world {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <a id="one" href="http://www.google.com">
    <p id="hello">Hello</p>
    <p id="world">World</p>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class on the [root / html](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:root) element ie:

```
var root =  document.querySelector(":root");
 if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {root.classList.add("touch")}
```

then use the [`negation CSS pseudo-class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
:root:not(.touch) #one:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
:root:not(.touch) #one:hover > #hello {
  display: none;
}
:root:not(.touch) #one:hover > #world {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
```

**alternative**

```
 var root =  document.querySelector(":root");
 'ontouchstart' in window ? root.classList.add("touch") : root.classList.add("no-touch")
```

then

```
.no-touch #one:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.no-touch #one:hover > #hello {
  display: none;
}
.no-touch #one:hover > #world {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
```

for touch

```
.touch #one{
  /*something else*/  
}
```